# How to refresh the app if it is opened from Background(not while in Background)

Tags: ios, swift

Please read through my scenario:

Step 1: User taps the app icon from home page first time (App State = **Foreground**)

Step 2: After some use in app, User taps the home button. (App State = **Background ?**)

Step 3: Now, if the User taps the app icon again, the app will be opened from where he left. (App State = **Foreground**)

My issue is when the user taps the app icon second time, i want to perform some action like refreshing the page. So how can I know that the app is opened from **Background**

**Note**: I dont want to refresh the app when it is background and I am not talking anything about force closing the app like double tap the home button and suspend the app to its **Inactive** state.

Comment: please explain in detail if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**Solution 1: AppDelegate**

In your *AppDelegate*, you can use `optional func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)`. This method will be called when "Step 3" will be reached.

**Solution 2: Notification**

At "Step 3", the system will also send the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. You can use that notification in one of your ViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

Could you do your refreshing in the applicationDidBecomeActive method in your AppDelegate?